# Unable to locate file on sdcard even though if it exists while customizing Android system's Setting app

Tags: android

I am working on customization of Android system's Setting app (i.e. Android's original source code), under which I need to get an image from Gallery to the Android'd Setting's app. The situation where I got stuck is when I'm trying the same from my app it works fine but when it comes to Android Setting's app I couldn't locate the path of an image in sdcard and finds NullPointerException.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access external storage from a program running as system UID.

You can use adb shell to check where is the mount point and the file mode at /mnt

```
shell@maguro:/ $ ls -l  /sdcard
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2013-10-05 06:09 sdcard -> /storage/emulated/legacy

shell@maguro:/ $ ls -l  /storage/emulated/legacy
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2013-10-05 06:09 legacy -> /mnt/shell/emulated/0

shell@maguro:/mnt $ ls -l
drwxr-xr-x root     system            2013-10-05 06:09 asec
drwxr-xr-x root     system            2013-10-05 06:09 obb
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2013-10-05 06:09 sdcard -> /storage/emulated/legacy
drwx------ root     root              2013-10-05 06:09 secure
drwx------ shell    shell             2013-10-05 06:09 shell
```

And you will see that external storage is not accessible for system user.

Although it is FUSE now since ICS, This is a legacy from old Android system, when user is able to umount the external SDCARD partition. At that time, if any process is accessing the external storage, vold will kill that process.

Forbidding system process to accessing the external storage is for this consideration - my guess.

Comment: I'm working over ICS source code, could you suggest any other way to access external storage in this case? or system user can never access to sdcard?
What if i delete android:shareUserId="android.uid.system" from AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Oh, this is another question. But since you are talking about settings application, this should be system UID, otherwise you won't be able to change secure system settings. Why do you want the settings application to access SDCARD? If you have to do that, try to implement another background service using another UID with declared permission to access external storage. And use binder interface to provide an pipe for your system UID program to access the SDCARD. Or, there might also be some other simple method, depends on your requirement.